# Remove character and remove whitespace in XQUERY

Tags: xml, xquery

What I am trying to achieve:

For a given string (`AA012345`), I need to check the value at index 3 in the string, if it is `0` I need to remove it and also remove the whitespace where the `0` would have been.

I have tried a few different things - if `substring(., 3,1)` is `0`, replace with '', but that did not work. As well as if `substring(., 3,1)` is `0`, remove character and then try to remove the whitespace.

Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Limited to using XQuery 1.0.

Thanks

Comment: Please add the actual code you have tried that isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by decomposing the string into three chunks (before position 3, position 3, after position 3) and reassembling it with a condition on the middle chunk:

```
xquery version "1.0";

let $string := "AA012345"
let $start := substring($string, 0, 3)
let $middle := substring($string, 3, 1)
let $end := substring($string, 4)
return concat($start, $middle[. ne "0"], $end)
```

It can also be made more verbose to optimize. If position 3 is not a zero, not all let clauses need to be evaluated.

```
xquery version "1.0";

let $string := "AA012345"
let $start := substring($string, 0, 3)
let $middle := substring($string, 3, 1)
let $end := substring($string, 4)
return if($middle eq "0")
       then concat($start, $end)
       else $string
```

Comment: Hi Ghislain, thanks for your response. I implemented something very similar to this after failing to get a replace function to work in the way I needed it to.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler: `replace("AA012345","^(.{2})(0)(.*)$","$1$3")`

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this does not appear to work. I get the same result back as the input, any ideas?

Comment: What is your XQuery processor & version?

Comment: Very nice, I restricted myself too much and had overlooked that regular expressions were already available in 1.0.

Comment: Oracle XQuery engine - version 1.0

Comment: When trying this in regex101.com,  it doesn't seem to find a match on the '0'. I'm not to savvy with Regex, but your statement looks correct from what I know.

Comment: It works for me on regex101.com, with `^(.{2})(0)(.*)$` and `AA012345`. I tested mholstege's query successfully both in Zorba and Saxon. Maybe there is something else that we're missing.